# Selectpicker class causing problems for me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

As soon as I use class="selectpicker" I was not able to load drop-down values in select.

So, for loading category values I added the script

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
//replaced i < 10 with i < Object.keys(e).length
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(e).length; i++) {
    var o = new Option(e[i].name, e[i].name);
    $(".selectpicker").append(o);
}
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');
```

Now, I am able to load category dropdown values but the same dropdown values are loading for services too. My doubt is that how can I write another selectpicker function for services too.

My HTML code is

```
<form action="" class="form-inline" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" id="categories">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <select id="lunchBegins" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Select Your City" v-model="category" name="category">
                    <option v-for="post in articles" v-bind:value="post.name">{{post.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <select id="basic" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" v-model="subcategory" name="subcategory">
                    <option v-for="so in services" v-bind:value="so.name">{{so.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My view js script for loading is

```
<script>
    categories = new Vue({
        el: '#categories',
        data: {
            articles: [],
            services: [],
            category: 0,
            subcategory: 0,
        },
        watch: {
            subcategory: function (e) {
                this.prefetch();
            },
            category: function () {
                var self = this;
                self.subcategory = 0;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_services/",
                    data: {
                        'service': self.id
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (e) {
                        console.log('Loading services');
                        console.log(self.category);
                        let categoryIdArray = self.articles.filter(x=>x.name == self.category);
                        console.log(categoryIdArray);
                        self.services = e.filter(x=>x.cat_id == categoryIdArray[0].cat_id);
                        self.prefetch();
                    }
                });
            },
        },

        mounted() {
            var vm = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_category/",
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
                    //replaced i < 10 with i < Object.keys(e).length
                    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(e).length; i++) {
                        var o = new Option(e[i].name, e[i].name);
                        $(".selectpicker").append(o);
                    }
                    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');
                    vm.articles = e;
                    console.log(vm);
                },
            });
        },
    })
</script>
```

Can somebody please help me to solve the problem.. I am behind this question for the few days.. How can I get the dropdown list for services too. When I remove class=selectpicker I am able to load correct dropdown list for services also. So, how can I fix the problem when I use the class="selectpicker"

Answer (score 0):

You have given selectpicker to both select tag so it will append options to both select tags.Just change your Jquery code like :

```js
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    //for category dropdown 
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(e).length; i++) {
      var o = new Option(e[i].name, e[i].name);
      $("#lunchBegins").append(o);
    }
    $("select[name='category']").selectpicker('refresh');


     //for service dropdown, object1 is just dummy
    for (var i = 0; i < Object1.keys(e).length; i++) {
      var o = new Option(e[i].name, e[i].name);
      $("#basic").append(o);
    }
    $("select[name='subcategory']").selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: can you please provide me a complete solution

Comment: i have given  for (var i = 1; i < categoryIdArray.keys(e).length; i++) for services but now when I load for first category no service is coming, for second category , services of first category is coming,,

Comment: Object1 is dummy name used by me you have to add your service object name there if you have.

Comment: sir, i am getting services in self.services

Comment: So use it where object1 is used if it is object.

Comment: but now when I load for first category no service is coming, for second category , services of first category is coming,

Comment: I think in your ajax call you are passing old id so it is happening so console your category id and check what is happening there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159959/discussion-between-secret-coder-and-kishan).

Comment: i am not getting sir